# SQL select-row-having-maximum when the maximising value is computed from the row

Tags: sql, mysql5

If I want to select the row which has the maximal value for a particular column, I can simply do this

```
SELECT * FROM tablename WHERE columnname=(SELECT MAX(columnname) FROM tablename)
```

My problem is twofold. Firstly, if this value isn't a column but the result of a stored procedure which operates on the row, what is the syntax? Something like

```
SELECT * FROM tablename
WHERE CALL procname (???)
   = (SELECT MAX (CALL procname (???) FROM tablename)
```

How do I flesh out this query?

Secondly, in this naive form, we call `procname` once on every row to determine `MAX(...)` and then potentially once *again* on each row to test whether each row has the maximum value.

How can I optimise this? I'm guessing it may have something to to with a temporary table, but I don't know how clever the engine is, I'm mentally comparing it to the performance of a C-style for-loop which would only have to maintain one row's values at a time.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have a numeric primary in `pkcol` and your calculation column `colname` is numeric also, you could try something like

```
SELECT
  @proc:=CALL procname(colname) AS dummy1,
  IF(@proc>@val,@id:=pkcol,@id) AS dummy2,
  IF(@proc>@val,@val:=@val,@val) AS dummy3
FROM
  (@id:=0) AS initid,
  (@val:=0) AS initval,
  tablename
;

-- discard query result

SELECT * FROM tablename WHERE pkcol=@id;
```

Which would be very close to your C construct.

Comment: Can you please give me a link which will explain the `@` and `:=` syntax? I'm not sure I understand this ... is it modifying the table in-place?

Comment: `@xxx` is a session variable - compare it to $xxx in PHP. The `:=` is the assignment operator (just as in Pascal). See http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/user-variables.html